Invalid read syntax error in org-roam-capture-templates
I have the following in my org-roam-capture-templates list:
("tt" "tomorrow task" plain
 ,(concat "*** %(org-read-date nil nil '+1')\n\n"
           "Description:\n\n"
           "Results:\n\n")
 :target (file "agenda.org"))

The overall list is backticked so concat will be evaluated with the preceding comma. I have other very similar templates that work just fine, and the unique element to this one is %(org-read-date nil nil '+1'). It's the only template in which I try to leverage the %(sexp) template form. When I try to use it, it opens a *Capture* buffer and successfully writes the plain text in the template, but the org-read-date form does not get expanded/evaluated, just written to the buffer literally. I thought it might be that it doesn't evaluate to a string, but it does when I evaluate it by itself in an elisp buffer.
What am I missing? Or is there a better way to represent 'tomorrow's date' in a roam template?

I don't think the %(org-read-date ...) form is the problem. Now I don't know anything about org-roam, so I don't know if org-roam-capture-templates (N.B: plural) requires different syntax, but the following seems to  work:
(setq org-roam-capture-templates `(("tt" "tomorrow task" plain
                                    ,(concat "*** %(org-read-date nil nil \"+1\")\n\n"
                                             "Description: \n\n"
                                             "Results: \n\n")
                                    :target (file "agenda.org"))))

The difference is the syntax of the fourth argument of org-read-date: it's a string and needs to be enclosed by double-quotes (which need to be escaped inside a string - maybe you are used to Python where you can use either single- or double-quotes?)

This worked, thanks.
